# submitting a form programatically in c#

Tags: c#

I am using an API to make a post request to a server
(http://example.com)
on the website The form gets filled out with my code but it doesn't actually get submitted. I've seen post where people give an HTML example and do some sort of on click submit method but I don't have access to the form in that way so is there anyway I can submit it?

I'm writing to the form like so...

```
            var ticketData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                Summary = "test",
                Impact = 1,
                DueDate = "2017-12-28",
                Priority = 1
            }, Formatting.Indented);
            using (Stream dataStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(dataStream))
                {
                    using (var writer = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter))
                    {
                        writer.WriteRaw(ticketData);
                        writer.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
```

How do I programmatically submit?
is there like a way to set submit to true? I don't know how to go about doing this

Comment: Since you write something with Http i assume you are using a controller action hence you cannot submit a form programmatically because the form is client side but your code is server side. You can return some sort of command encoded in the Json data and transform it to some javascript code that submits the form but that seem not ideal to say the least. Also your question is not complete. What does the form look like?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: as suggested in the comments, added an explanation below.

```
public async Task PostForm(Uri requestUri, string json)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        await httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, content);
    }
}
```

This function uses the HttpClient to post the form data you serialized to json to a specific URL (requesturi). That URL is the URL of the POST action of the website you want to post to

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.